# How do i set a variable using conditional statements?

Tags: jquery

This does not work, even though putting a simple print ("foo") in the function block does work.

```
<script>

var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var X;

$(function() {

    if (viewportHeight >= 600) {
         var X = 100;
       }
});
</script>
```

Comment: you have 2 different X variables, delete the second var.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `var` keyword is used to create a variable whose scope is assigned to whatever `function` it is in. If it is not inside a function, its scope is the `window`, making it a global variable. If you omit the `var` keyword, the js engine will look up the scope chain for the closest definition of the variable. So, by using `var` inside the function, you are creating a new variable called `X` that is local to that function. If you omit the `var` keyword inside the function, it will look up the scope chain and find the `var X` that you defined above.

```
<script>

var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var X;

$(function() {

    if (viewportHeight >= 600) {
        X = 100; //don't use var if you want to access the above X
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: PS. This works because redefining in function scope results in the creation of a local variable, different from the one defined outside the function. Look out for closure.

Comment: @user1361747 Glad it worked! Be sure to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents, but you could write this whole thing as a single expression.

```
  var X = $(window).height() >= 600 ? 100 : null;
```

this seems like a place for good oll shorthand